# Recover Ubuntu partition

Tags: boot, partitioning

I have a Mac Book Pro laptop (2009) where I had the following partitions: Mac OS X 10.5.8 about 400 GB, EFI 200 MB ,EXT4 80 GB, LINUX SWAP 1 GB. I installed the linux ubuntu 16.04 LTS because I got stuck with the older Mac OS.

Now, I've copied all files from the Mac OS to external disk and wanted to rearrange the partitions to only have Ubuntu and all the space for the Ubuntu system.

I removed all partitions except EXT4. created a bigger LINUX SWAP of 4 GB. I had to copy the EXT4 partition to be able to expand its size.

Now, I try to boot but I get the grub rescue screen and no further boot. I've used the app 'Boot-repair' to create a analysis which can be found here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zsytDwyfDn/

Who could give me a step-by-step procedure to solve this boot problem and to recover my Ubuntu desktop with its files.

Many thanks in advance,
Michiel

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

Make sure you have a partition formatted in FAT32 of a few megabytes
   size. Set the flag 'BIOS_GRUB' for it with program GParted on the
   Ubuntu LiveCD.

Then using the procedure from [this website](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/ways-to-rescue-or-recover-grub-menu):
 Restart PC to get to the Grub rescue:
Type ls and hit enter. You will now see many partitions which are
   present on your PC. [e.g. (hd0),(hd0,msdos1)(hd0,msdos2)].

Select the partition in which your linux distro is installed.

enter this command set prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub  (Tip: - if you
   don’t remember the partition,try entering the command with every
   option. If wrong you will get an error message. If right you will
   proceed)

enter this command insmod normal and then normal.  Now your PC/Laptop
   will reboot and you will be on your desktop.

Now hit Ctrl+Alt+T and open terminal and type sudo update-grub and
   then sudo grub-install /dev/sda. You may be asked for your password,
   type it, the password will remain invisible and this is normal.